# Spring Security with Cookie just by using a filter

Tags: spring-security

I have a backend application that is called from a web client.
With the call, a cookie is sent that contains a session id that has been successfully validated by the client.

In the backend, I only want to check whether the session id sent by the cookie is valid.
(CSRF will be considered too)

Is it not sufficient to simply create a filter that contacts the sso system to check the session id contained in the cookie?

Security Config:

```
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new SsoFilter(authenticationManager()));
```

and a filter:

```
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws
          IOException, ServletException {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    if(cookies == null || cookies.length == 0){
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    Cookie tokenCookie = null;

    for (Cookie cookie : cookies){
      if (cookie.getName().equals(COOKIE_NAME)){
        tokenCookie = cookie;
      }
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthentication(tokenCookie.getValue());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(String token) {
    final Useruser= ssoService.validateToken(token);
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null, null);
  }
```

Comment: You might consider using `AuthenticationFilter` to formalize the structure and still take advantage of Spring Security's various authentication features. Other than that, it's reasonable to add a custom filter to perform a custom authentication strategy.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, will check the AuthenticationFilter